# Neural Network does not learn regression

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression, pytorch

I have the following setup:

- 2 input neurons (I1, I2)
- 2 output neurons (O1, O2)
- 1 hidden layer with 3 neurons (H1, H2, H3)
- loss function = mse
- optimizer = Adam
- the values from I1 range from 0 - 100
- the values from I2 range from 0 - 500
- batch size = 16
- learning rate = 0.1

The ANN should learn the following rules (regression problem):

1. If I1 increasing O1 decreasing
2. If I1 increasing O2 increasing
3. If I2 increasing O1 constant
4. If I2 increasing O1 decreasing

I am using the following model:

```
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=2)

    def forward(self, t):
        t = F.relu(self.fc1(t))
        t = self.out(t)
        return t
```

However, it does not learn. My question is, which part should I focus on?
Is a linear, fully connected network maybe not suitable for the rules (no linear regression)? Do I need more hidden layers / more neurons? Is the learning rate a problem? Should the input data be normalized?

I tinkered around a lot, but didn't get any improvements.

Comment: Although the suggested duplicate is classification using Torch, it is the exact same problem, and a common beginner's problem.

Comment: As you suggested, I normalized I1 with value / 100 and I2 with value / 500. So I always have values between 0-1. Unfortunately, the improvement is very limited.

Comment: Sorry, that looked like a clear problem to me. It seems the code, deign or data have other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

The learning rate is too high. Make it between 0.001 and 0.0001. It's also possible that your hidden layer may not have modeled the relationship well. Try doubling/incrementing the neurons in the hidden layer like 4, 8, 12, 16, and then chose the appropriate one.